# Help: $b^{k(k-2)} \ll_k b^{4.2(k-2)}b^{8.4+2k}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-explanation

In the paper [linear forms in the logarithms of real algebraic numbers close to 1](http://irma.math.unistra.fr/~bugeaud/travaux/ConfMumbaidef.pdf), it is written on page $9$ that

> that is, by (12),
>   $$b^{k(k-2)} \ll a^{k(k-2)} (a^2b^2)^{2.1(k-2)} \ll_k  b^{4.2(k-2)}b^{8.4+2k}$$

Equation (12) is-
$$b \geq (k^ka^{a-2})^\frac{1}{2} $$

Here, $3 \leq k \leq 149, 2^{49} < a, 2< b .$

I couldn't figure out how $ a^{k(k-2)} (a^2b^2)^{2.1(k-2)} \ll_k  b^{4.2(k-2)}b^{8.4+2k}$

So, how do we prove

$ a^{k(k-2)} (a^2b^2)^{2.1(k-2)} \ll_k  b^{4.2(k-2)}b^{8.4+2k}$
?

**Edit:**

$ a^{k(k-2)} (a^2b^2)^{2.1(k-2)} \ll_k  b^{4.2(k-2)}b^{8.4+2k}$

$\implies a^{k(k-2)} (a^2)^{2.1(k-2)} (b^2)^{2.1(k-2)} \ll_k  b^{4.2(k-2)}b^{8.4+2k}$

$ \implies  a^{k(k-2)} a^{4.2(k-2)} b^{4.2(k-2)} \ll_k  b^{4.2(k-2)}b^{8.4+2k}$

$ \implies  a^{k(k-2)} a^{4.2(k-2)}  \ll_k  b^{8.4+2k}$

$ \implies  a^{(k-2)(k+ 4.2)}  \ll_k  b^{8.4+2k}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: Fixed a calculation mistake**

From $a>k$, $k^k>1$ and $b \geq (k^ka^{a-2})^\frac{1}{2}$, $b\geq (a^{a-2})^\frac{1}{2}>(a^{k-2})^\frac{1}{2}=a^\frac{k-2}{2}$.

Since $b$ cancels out in your equation, it remains to prove that $a^{k(k-2)+4.2(k-2)}<b^{8.4+2k}$, or $a^{(k-2)(k+4.2)}<b^{2(k+4.2)}$. Applying $b>a^\frac{k-2}{2}$ immediately gives the desired result.

Comment: Applying $b>a^{k-1}$, we need to prove that $(k+4.2)(k-2)<4.2(k-1)(k-2)$.... how?

Comment: It is just first-order inequality after cancelling out $k-2$.

Comment: We need to prove, $ a^{k(k-2)} (a^2b^2)^{2.1(k-2)} \ll_k  b^{4.2(k-2)}b^{8.4+2k}$$\implies a^{k(k-2)} (a^2)^{2.1(k-2)} (b^2)^{2.1(k-2)} \ll_k  b^{4.2(k-2)}b^{8.4+2k}$$ \implies  a^{k(k-2)} a^{4.2(k-2)} b^{4.2(k-2)} \ll_k  b^{4.2(k-2)}b^{8.4+2k}$
$ \implies  a^{k(k-2)} a^{4.2(k-2)}  \ll_k  b^{8.4+2k}$$ \implies  a^{(k-2)(k+ 4.2)}  \ll_k  b^{8.4+2k}$Note, $  a^{(k-2)(k+ 4.2)}  \ll_k  b^{(k-2)(k+ 4.2)}$ [ $\because b>a^{k-1}$]
So,it is sufficient to prove -$b^{(k-2)(k+ 4.2)} \ll_k  b^{8.4+2k} \implies (k-2)(k+ 4.2) \ll_k  8.4+2k$  how did u get $(k+4.2)(k-2)<4.2(k-1)(k-2)$? isn't it wrong?